# Have any parallel option for javascript querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm figuring out How I can select the current class by pure js, I building a video slider have multiple videos, query selector works perfectly for one video, adding more videos querySelector selection first element, but the slide dynamically changes the HTML class to the next div.

```js
var slide = 0,
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.cover-background > .video_container'),
    numSlides = slides.length;

    //Functions!!
    currentSlide = function() {
      var itemToShow = Math.abs(slide % numSlides);
      [].forEach.call(slides, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove('current_video')
      });
      slides[itemToShow].classList.add('current_video');
      resetProgress();
      resetInterval();
    },         
    next = function() {
      slide++;
      currentSlide();
    },
    prev = function() {
      slide--;
      currentSlide();
    },
    resetProgress = function() {
      var elm = document.querySelector('.progressbar'),
          newone = elm.cloneNode(true),
          x = elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    },
    resetslide = function() {
      var elm = document.querySelector('#slides > li'),
          newone = elm.cloneNode(true),
          x = elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    },
    resetInterval = function() {
      clearInterval(autonext);
      autonext = setInterval(function() {
        slide++;
        currentSlide();
      }, 10000);
    },
    autonext = setInterval(function() {
      next();
    }, 10000);
    let video = document.querySelectorAll(".current_video > .video");
    console.log(video);
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.load();
```

```html
    <div class="cover-background">
                <div id="first" class="video_container current_video" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div id="second" class="video_container" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div> 
                <div id="third" class="video_container" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

.current_video class dynamically move to next slide. the console log always gets the first one. also tried with `querySelectorAll` and  `getElementsByClassName()` I'm looking a pure javascript solution.

Comment: what result do you want to get, `<div id="first" class="video_container current_video" data-key="0">` ?

Comment: So you want to log just the div with the `.current_video` class?

Comment: @stax Yes I need to get the current class `.current_video > .video `

Comment: The selector looks fine. Aren't you using the javascript before the HTML exists?

Comment: @NoufalBinu you need to tell what exactly you want,

element as whole or just want to get classes only?

Comment: may your selector is already cached? could you provide more context on the JS side?

Comment: @Afzal K. @digitalniweb When the slide moves to another div `.current_video > .video` the value of the .video element not changing to another one. I will update the code

Comment: @Afzal K.
 updated with the whole code.

Comment: @André Kelling updated js

Comment: your console log is just called once in your script. so it can't log multiple times and will just log once the current video. i guess your script is running inside of some other script?!

Comment: @ André Kelling No

Comment: @André Kelling also checked with inside chrome console `console.log(video)` always get video_1.mp4

Comment: The current video needs to be accessed and logged within the `next` function. The current code ... `let video = document.querySelectorAll(".current_video > .video"); console.log(video);` ... gets executed exactly once, reporting the initial state of the DOM.

Comment: @NoufalBinu, wrapped it inside function, then calling from inside `currentSlide function` where it adds the class

Comment: @Afzal K. Not working, still getting the first video.

Comment: @NoufalBinu as i understood, you wanted it this way, that when class is added it, it console logs,

it is doing the same, when current class is added it console logs it

Comment: on initial call it logs first, then when class is added to next it logs the next

Comment: because if you wanted to log all at once, there was no need to add class only to one, as current class is added to only one element at a time

Comment: @NoufalBinu just edited the answer and added the border, stolen the concept from earlier answer

Comment: @AfzalK. I know, but I can't, can you check it on your end?

Comment: check the code on diff checker if the answer is working as you wanted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the code by adding the `querySelector` inside the function that is called when the current_video class is added. This ensures that the function is called whenever the class is added, providing a simpler and more efficient workaround.

```js
var slide = 0,
    slides = document.querySelectorAll('.cover-background > .video_container'),
    numSlides = slides.length;

    //Functions!!
    currentSlide = function() {
      var itemToShow = Math.abs(slide % numSlides);
      [].forEach.call(slides, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove('current_video')
      });
      slides[itemToShow].classList.add('current_video');
      checkup(); // Call checkup function when current_video class is added
      resetProgress();
      resetInterval();
    },         
    next = function() {
      slide++;
      currentSlide();
    },
    prev = function() {
      slide--;
      currentSlide();
    },
    resetProgress = function() {
      var elm = document.querySelector('.progressbar'),
          newone = elm.cloneNode(true),
          x = elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    },
    resetslide = function() {
      var elm = document.querySelector('#slides > li'),
          newone = elm.cloneNode(true),
          x = elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    },
    resetInterval = function() {
      clearInterval(autonext);
      autonext = setInterval(function() {
        slide++;
        currentSlide();
      }, 10000);
    },
    autonext = setInterval(function() {
      next();
    }, 10000);
    
    function checkup(){ // wrapped inside function
    let video = document.querySelector(".current_video > .video");
    console.log(video);
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.load();
    };
    checkup() // initial call
```

```css
.current_video {border: 2px solid red}
.video_container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
    <div class="cover-background">
                <div id="first" class="video_container current_video" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div id="second" class="video_container" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div> 
                <div id="third" class="video_container" data-key="0">
                    <video class="video"  width="100%" height="auto" autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="videos/video_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it is working !!! Thank you so much, Also I used with @CarstenMassmann minimal code. thanks, both.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to progress through your slider after a set interval then you can do that in a much simpler way:

```js
let slide=0, slides=document.querySelectorAll('.cover-background > .video_container');

let auto;
function startSl(){
 stopSl();
 auto=setInterval(nextSl, 1000);
}
function stopSl(){
 clearInterval(auto);
}
function nextSl(){
  slides[slide].classList.remove("current_video")
  slide=(slide+1)%slides.length;
  slides[slide].classList.add("current_video")
}
startSl();
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((b,i)=>b.onclick=[startSl,stopSl][i]);
```

```css
.current_video {border: 2px solid red}
```

```html
<button>start</button><button>stop</button>
<div class="cover-background">
 <div id="first" class="video_container current_video" data-key="0">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/120/80">
 </div>
 <div id="second" class="video_container" data-key="0">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/120/80">
 </div> 
 <div id="third" class="video_container" data-key="0">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/120/80">
 </div>  
</div>
```

In this snippet I replaced the videos by images and made the `.current_video` class have a red border.

Comment: Yes, why not ;-) ... Let's add that, as suggested. Thanks, @PeterSeliger! Without it a user could have created a stack of "unstoppable" interval jobs :D.

Comment: Now It is a simpler way! thank you.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann, it was possible to get it called from inside `currentSlide function` where it was also adding the class